# Removing "," at the beginning of a line CSV

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, string, csv

i want to convert a .csv file and write a new one. However I am not able to remove the first , i am kinda stuck here and it is driving me crazy.
This is my code:

```
    var extractedtasks = tasks.slice(0, 3)
    var extractedtasksformated = extractedtasks.toString().replace(/,$/g, "\n")

    let csvformat = "EMAIL,PASSWORD,MAILBOX"
    fs.writeFileSync(tasklocation[0], csvformat + "\n" + extractedtasksformated.replace(/,^/g, 
    ""))
    console.log(chalk.green("Successfully updated the CSV file"))
```

That's the output i am getting in the newly generated file

```
EMAIL,PASSWORD,MAILBOX
example1@gmail.com,Password123,example@gmail.com:password
,example2@gmail.com,Password123,example@gmail.com:password
,example3@gmail.com,Password123,example@gmail.com:password
```

Output extractedtasks:

```
[
  'example1@gmail.com,Password123,example@gmail.com:password\r',
  'example2@gmail.com,Password123,example@gmail.com:password\r',
  'example3@gmail.com,Password123,example@gmail.com:password\r'
]
```

Output extractedtasksformated:

```
,example3@gmail.com,Password123,example@gmail.com:passwordxample@gmail.com:password
```

Comment: Your caret (start of line) needs to be before the comma: in your second replacement `extractedtasksformated.replace(/^,/g, ""))`

Comment: hi @SimonK thanks for ur quick response I am still getting the same result as before :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `extractedtasks` is an array, instead of converting it to a string you should just join it with the expected separator:

```js
extractedtasks = [
  'example1@gmail.com,Password123,example@gmail.com:password\r',
  'example2@gmail.com,Password123,example@gmail.com:password\r',
  'example3@gmail.com,Password123,example@gmail.com:password\r'
]

extractedtasksJoined = extractedtasks.join("\n")
// "example1@gmail.com,Password123,example@gmail.com:password\r\nexample2@gmail.com..."

// depending on the target line separator, you should also probably
// remove the "\r"
extractedtasksJoined = extractedtasksJoined.replace("\r", "")

// finally
fs.writeFileSync(tasklocation[0], csvformat + "\n" + extractedtasksJoined + "\n")
```

Comment: Hey thank you for your fast reply unfortunatley this doesnt work for me :( I have no idea why if i replace it with "x" instead of "" it replaces the , with ","

Comment: It would be very helpful if you printed out the value of `extractedtasksformated` and posted here.

Comment: hey @rewritten I have edited my question with the output :)

Comment: @MaxiiPaguera check now